# How to create a new file from Finder's context menu?

Tags: macos, finder, libreoffice

Could you tell me how to add a menu item into Finder's contextual menu (the one I get when I <kbd>Control</kbd>-click in a folder)?

When I create a document or spreadsheet using LibreOffice, I usually run LibreOffice first and then choose Text documents, or I choose the item of LibreOffice's contextual menu from the Dock. But, the new document is not created under a specific folder. So I have to choose the folder and enter a name for the file to save.

I would like to create LibreOffice text documents or spreadsheets by using a menu item. It should create the documents under the folder I'm in.

This is a screenshot of the contextual menu when I press <kbd>Control</kbd>-click in folder.

[image: folder view]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### XtraFinder

**Update 2021:** This app requires you to disable System Integrity Protection in macOS, which is not recommended. Therefore, this cannot be recommended for normal users.

The free app [XtraFinder](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/) gives you an option to add a *New File* entry to the contextual menu in Finder windows (amongst others, like opening a Terminal window):

[image]

You can manage the templates for files easily:

[image]

All you'd have to do is add an empty LibreOffice file in that template directory.

Comment: ♦ It worked! Thank you very much for the information in detail.

Comment: Will it work also in high sierra ( latest) ? - and do I need to reboot the mac with the special key ?

Comment: @Royi No need to reboot. It should be compatible with High Sierra, but please check on the website.

Comment: I meant do i need to use the regular download button or the bottom one http://imgur.com/gallery/ZZvI0Sb

Comment: @Royi Please just try the regular version. There's no reason for it not to work.

Comment: This looks perfect, and it's still available in 2021, but since Catalina 10.15.4 it requires you to disable System Integrity Protection. https://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/doc/index.html#line4 Don't know if I want to do that. The same change from Apple killed other Finder apps like TotalFinder.

Comment: Disabling System Integrity Protection? Don't!